# Visual Studio 2015 -Release Folder

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I want the related files to the project to be saved to release folder everytime the project is run.I want the files to overwrite the files if they already exist in release folder when I run tha project.

I know there is a window pane that has this option.I am not able to recall.

Has anyone any idea about this? Please help!

Answer (score 1):

YOu need to include the files in your project ....

[image]

Remember to set the filter to all files so you can see them

[image]

Then use the files properties to set the copy mode.

[image]